# Why can't unimolecular reactions be 2nd order?

Tags: reaction-mechanism

Why can't unimolecular reactions be second order? For example, doubling the concentration of a single reactant would result in four times the original rate of reaction.

Answer (score 5):

A first order reaction involves the behavior of individual particles, usually their decomposition into smaller, more reactive species.  The rate of such a reaction relies solely on the number of particles present, so if we double the number of particles then the rate doubles simply because there are twice as many particles available to decompose.

A second order reaction involves the interaction of two particles with one another. (Even if both particles are the same it is still a bimolecular reaction.)  If we double the concentration of either species we double the likelihood of a collision between those species.  If both species are the same (ex: $\ce{2A -> A2}$) then the result of doubling the concentration is a quadrupling of the rate because we simultaneously double the number of particles that can interact and the number of interactions that can occur.

An metaphorical example involving people:

**Unimolecular**:
A couple can spontaneously break up into two separate people because of its internal properties.  (Assume there are no intercouple issues involved here.)

$\ce{C -> M + W}$

If we double the number of couples we would expect breakups to occur twice as often because there are twice as many couples to be broken up.  However, since there are no intercouple issues in this example, adding additional couples to our consideration does not increase the likelihood of existing couples breaking up.

**Bimolecular with Two Different Species**:
A man and a woman can join together to make a couple if they collide in the right orientation with enough energy. :-)

$\ce{M + W -> C}$

If I increase the number of either men or women, it is more likely that I will form a couple simply because there are more interactions between men and women occurring.  Each species' increase is first order though, since they require a partner of the other gender to couple with.  i.e. Doubling the number of women only doubles the rate at which couples are formed because they still have to connect with a man, and the number of men has not changed.

**Bimolecular with a Single Species**:
Homosexual men can join together to form a couple.
$\ce{M + M -> C'}$

If I double the number of men, then each additional man can interact with every other man in the room, greatly increasing the likelihood of a couple forming.  This means that not only are there more men available to make couples (the first doubling of the rate), but that the existing men are also more likely to be involved in a connection that results in a new couple being formed (the second doubling of the rate.)

Comment: `A man and a woman can join together to make a couple if they collide in the right orientation with enough energy. :-)` Finally a practical tip to find a partner. I'll try it out immediately and tell you how it worked out :) Awesome answer.

Answer (score 0):

This question is provocative, but there appears to be a contradiction in terms. If a reaction is unimolecular, its rate must not depend on the concentration of any other molecule including molecules of the same identity. Certainly in dilute solution, a reacting molecule in a unimolecular reaction cannot be influenced by its neighbors. At the level of stochastics there appears to be no information in the electronic (or nuclear) structure of the reacting molecule that could impart some "knowledge" of the presence of more or fewer neighboring molecules of the same kind. The rate law for a single molecule becomes just a probability; the only reason the macroscopic rate law is proportional to concentration is that to get the overall flux you have to apply that probability to all the molecules present. For example, the classic unimolecular, first order process is radioactive decay. Here the reaction is entirely nuclear (unless we are talking chain reactions - but those are bi-"molecular"), completely insulated from its neighbors by electrons, and its observed rate is first order over many orders of magnitude in initial conditions.

We could consider extremely crowded molecular environments such as some investigators think exists in the cell cytosol, but I think we could go all the way to solid state chemistry and not really address the question being asked because if you get the neighboring molecules close enough to influence the reaction rate in any way, you have, by definition, a bimolecular reaction. If we read the question as "What prevents the reaction kinetics of a unimolecular reaction from depending on the square of the concentration?", I think the answer must be that there is no physical force that could influence the local electronic chemical interactions based on the macroscopic concentration of reacting molecules.

One situation that almost meets the requirements of the question is the case where the unimolecular reaction is enzyme-catalyzed. In this case it's possible that the molecule itself is an allosteric activator and the kinetic law would have a term in S^2. A typical kinetic law for a reaction where S is the substrate and A is the activator is Flux = (Vm*S/Ks + b*Vm*A*S/(Ka*Ks)) / (1 + S/Ks + (A*S)/(KaKs)). You can see that if A=S then the rate law has both numerator and denominator terms in S^2.